# Regex for Words with Apostrophes (Java)

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to figure out the regex to match strings that contain only letters and apostrophes. If a string contains an apostrophe, I only want to match it if there is a letter on both sides of it.

What I have so far is `[a-zA-Z]+('[a-zA-Z])?`

I want to match strings like:

```
a'a
aa'a
a'aaa
```

But not:

```
bb'
'bb
```

Comment: Does this have to be done with regex? It's tricky considering that there can be many apostrophes and their neighbourhood can overlap (as in `a'a'a'a`).

Comment: I would be happy with a solution without regex, I just thought it would be easiest with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there, just you need to add `+` after the char class present inside the optional group.

```
^[a-zA-Z]+('[a-zA-Z]+)?$
```

**OR**

Use this if you want to deal with more than one apostrophe.

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(?:'[a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xU2jI8/1)

```
String s = "a'a'a'a a' a'a-'bb";
String parts[] = s.split("[ -]");
for(String i:parts) {
    if(!i.isEmpty())
    {
    System.out.println(i + " => " + i.matches("[a-zA-Z]+(?:'[a-zA-Z]+)*"));
}
}
```

**Output:**

```
a'a'a'a => true
a' => false
a'a => true
'bb => false
```

Comment: I read in words from a plain txt file, splitting on spaces, then check to see if it matches the pattern.     String[] wordsArray = document.split("[- ]");
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(wordsArray));
        for(String word : words){
         if(!word.isEmpty() && word.matches("[a-zA-Z]+(?:'[a-zA-Z]+)*")){

Comment: check for any chars other than letters or hyphens in the array list.

Comment: This is my txt file... a’a aaa acc AaA aZz a1 a’ ‘a ‘a’ abbbZ’ ‘b b’’ b’’b b’b bb’bb BB’BB B’B B’BBBBB B’B’B’B ‘ BB’b.     It is only matching the aaa, acc, AaA and aZz

Comment: oh the file contains a different apostrophe.. did you not that? just put the two diff apostrophe in a char class like `^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[‘'’][a-zA-Z]+)*$`

Comment: No, it's plain text, I assumed it would be the same. How can I fix that?

Comment: yep, you could also use character class. Check the regex in the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "a'a'a";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+(?:'[a-zA-Z]+)*$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println("true");
        } else {
            System.out.println("false");
        }

    }
```

**output**

```
false
```