# Regex for just alphabetic characters only - Java

Tags: java, regex

Sorry I am new to Regex, but I can't seem to achieve the following with any regex I have tried so far.

**We are interested in "words" (i.e. the word is wholly alphabetic containing only letters of the alphabet in upper, lower or mixed case. ALL other content is ignored)**

An example String which I have trying to work with is as follows:

*To find the golden ticket you have to buy a bar of chocolate :) Charlie’s Granny and Grandad are hoping he gets a ticket but he only has enough money to buy 1 bar. I printed 5 tickets but my Oompa-Loompa workers made more than 1000000 bars :)*

So words like Charlie's, Oompa-Loompa and the smiley face should not be included in the output. Just the wholly alphabetic words.

I have tried using some of the examples from other questions such as this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618493/regex-for-words-with-apostrophes-java) attempting to use Regex's such as *^[a-zA-Z]+('[a-zA-Z]+)?$* but unfortunately as I stated previously, I am new to Regex so I'm not too sure what I am doing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "[a-zA-Z]+" match alphabetic words (only letters)... You can use pages like [this](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) to test your regex in Java in a simple way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Description

This regex will do the following:

- Assume words are entirely made up of alphabetical characters A-Z, upper case and lower case
- Find all words
- Ignore all strings that contain non-alphabetical characters or symbols
- Assumes some punctuation like periods or commas are to be ignored but the preceding word should be captured.

**The Regex**

```
(?<=\s|^)[a-zA-Z]*(?=[.,;:]?\s|$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   ^                         start of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-zA-Z]*                any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
                           (0 or more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [.,;:]?                  any character of: '.', ',', ';', ':'
                             (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Examples

**Online Regex demo**

http://fiddle.re/65eqna

**Sample Java Code**

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
class Module1{
  public static void main(String[] asd){
  String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
  Pattern re = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\s|^)[a-zA-Z]*(?=[.,;:]?\\s|$)");
  Matcher m = re.matcher(sourcestring);
  int mIdx = 0;
    while (m.find()){
      for( int groupIdx = 0; groupIdx < m.groupCount()+1; groupIdx++ ){
        System.out.println( "[" + mIdx + "][" + groupIdx + "] = " + m.group(groupIdx));
      }
      mIdx++;
    }
  }
}
```

**Sample Captures**

```
$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => To
            [1] => find
            [2] => the
            [3] => golden
            [4] => ticket
            [5] => you
            [6] => have
            [7] => to
            [8] => buy
            [9] => a
            [10] => bar
            [11] => of
            [12] => chocolate
            [13] => Granny
            [14] => and
            [15] => Grandad
            [16] => are
            [17] => hoping
            [18] => he
            [19] => gets
            [20] => a
            [21] => ticket
            [22] => but
            [23] => he
            [24] => only
            [25] => has
            [26] => enough
            [27] => money
            [28] => to
            [29] => buy
            [30] => bar
            [31] => I
            [32] => printed
            [33] => tickets
            [34] => but
            [35] => my
            [36] => workers
            [37] => made
            [38] => more
            [39] => than
            [40] => bars
        )

)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
words.split("[ ]+");
```

Then for each string in that array the following will be `true` if it meets your criteria:

```
str.matches("[a-zA-Z]+");
```